# Make menu items not overflow on zoom in

Tags: html, css

I made a menu out of floated buttons, but when zooming in or browsing on a tablet/phone, the last 1-2 items will overflow and go on a second line. That happens because that's how float works.

How can I make all the menu items displayed on a single line, no matter how small the screen is?

For instance, zoom into this and see that #4 goes under my menu.

```css
#top{
   background-color:red;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
}
#but1,#but2,#but3,#but4{
  float:left;
    width:20%;
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
  text-align:center;
    margin:10px;
    height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="top">
    <div id="but1">1</div>
    <div id="but2">2</div>
    <div id="but3">3</div>
    <div id="but4">4</div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: If your `#top` has a finite width then it won't wrap. Assuming it is modified so it actually contains the floating elements. http://jsfiddle.net/dkqg92b7/ resize to see how the item are not wrapping. Perhaps it's best to give it a min-width in your case

Comment: Well the thing is I want it to occupy the whole page width. If there is an alternative to floating, please tell me.

Comment: As I mentioned it in my comment, use `min-width` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width

Comment: min-width:100% won't work. They still overflow.

Comment: I didn't say set it to 100%, your min-width should be the shortest width that your menu can go, 320px is probably safe, I don't think anyone is using devices that has smaller than 320. For smaller screens, if you want those long text lines to stay on one line then reduce your font size until they fit. Here is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: `min-width: 320px` in your `top` class. This will prevent the div overflowing on browser sizes smaller than 320px wide.

Comment: Still won't work for me. I went for Oriol's answer since it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the margin, which isn't included in `width`.

Here are some approaches:

- Use a percentage in the margin, instead of a fixed length:

  ```css
  #but1, #but2, #but3, #but4 {
    margin: 2.5%;
  }
  ```

  Now, `4 * (2.5% + 20% + 2.5%) = 4 * 25% = 100%`.

  ```css
      #top {
        background-color: red;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
      }
      #but1, #but2, #but3, #but4 {
        float: left;
        width: 20%;
        background-color: blue;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 2.5%;
        height: 50px;
      }
  ```

  ```html
      <div id="top">
        <div id="but1">1</div>
        <div id="but2">2</div>
        <div id="but3">3</div>
        <div id="but4">4</div>
      </div>
  ```
- Use [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to subtract the margin from the width:

  ```css
  #but1, #but2, #but3, #but4 {
    width: calc(25% - 20px);
  }
  ```

  ```css
      #top {
        background-color: red;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
      }
      #but1, #but2, #but3, #but4 {
        float: left;
        width: calc(25% - 20px);
        background-color: blue;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 10px;
        height: 50px;
      }
  ```

  ```html
      <div id="top">
        <div id="but1">1</div>
        <div id="but2">2</div>
        <div id="but3">3</div>
        <div id="but4">4</div>
      </div>
  ```
- Use [flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) (with the default [`flex-wrap: nowrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap)):

  ```css
  #top {
    display: flex;
  }
  ```

  ```css
      #top {
        background-color: red;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        display: flex;
      }
      #but1, #but2, #but3, #but4 {
        float: left;
        width: 25%;
        background-color: blue;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 10px;
        height: 50px;
      }
  ```

  ```html
      <div id="top">
        <div id="but1">1</div>
        <div id="but2">2</div>
        <div id="but3">3</div>
        <div id="but4">4</div>
      </div>
  ```

Comment: O is that what he meant? that was confusing

Comment: Ok, the min-width worked as well. I wasn't including the margins there, neither. In that case, your answer still solved my issue. Thank you everyone.